# Unable to modify AD attribute via java code in Eclipse / Spring

Tags: java, spring, active-directory

I am attempting to modify an AD attribute via Java using the Spring framework

Here is the error message I am getting:

> DAP: error code 65 - 0000207D: UpdErr: DSID-0315166D, problem 6002 (OBJ_CLASS_VIOLATION), data 589832 remaining name 'OU=Agents,OU=Customers,DC=zextdstest,DC=local'

```
public void confirmAccount(User user)   {   
    Attribute attribute = new BasicAttribute(Constants.USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL_ATTR, Constants.ACCOUNT_PROPERTIES.toString());       
    ModificationItem mod = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attribute);           this.ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(this.getBaseDistinguishedName(user), new ModificationItem[] { mod });    
}
```

When I modify other attributes it works fine. Just on this one it fails.